# PHP upload multiple files code assistance

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I have some code running on my site which works well to upload single files from file input form elements - but I now need a multiple file input form element to accept more than 1 file and upload them all to the server and store the details of the filenames uploaded in a comma separated string... Any ideas on how to make this work with the code I am using below:

form field:

```
<input name="logoexamples[]" id="blogoexamples" type="file" class="textInput" value="notrelevant" multiple>
```

PHP code (that works to accept 1 file uploaded, but not more than 1....?):

```
<?php
// initialize output;
$output = true;

// valid extensions
$ext_array = array('pdf', 'txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'eps', 'svg', 'gif', 'ai');

// create unique path for this form submission
//$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/';

// you can create some logic to automatically
// generate some type of folder structure here.
// the path that you specify will automatically
// be created by the script if it doesn't already
// exist.

// UPLOAD TO FOLDER IN /ASSETS/UPLOADS/ WITH ID OF THE PARENT PROJECT FOLDER RESOURCE 

// Get page ID
// $pageid = $modx->resource->get('id');
// $uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/'.$pageid.'/';

// Get parent page title
$parentObj = $modx->resource->getOne('Parent');
$parentpageid = $parentObj->get('pagetitle');
$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/'.$parentpageid.'/';

// get full path to unique folder
$target_path = $modx->config['base_path'] . $uploadpath;

// get uploaded file names:
$submittedfiles = array_keys($_FILES);

// loop through files
foreach ($submittedfiles as $sf) {


// Get Filename and make sure its good.
$filename = basename( $_FILES[$sf]['name'] );

// Get file's extension
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = mb_strtolower($ext); // case insensitive

// is the file name empty (no file uploaded)
if($filename != '') {

    // is this the right type of file?
    if(in_array($ext, $ext_array)) {

        // clean up file name and make unique
        $filename = mb_strtolower($filename); // to lowercase
        $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename); // spaces to underscores
        $filename = date("Y-m-d_G-i-s_") . $filename; // add date & time

        // full path to new file
        $myTarget = $target_path . $filename;

// JWD - save uploaded filenames as a session var to get it on the redirect hook
$_SESSION['briefing_submittedfiles_' . $sf] = 'http://www.example.com/assets/uploads/'.$parentpageid.'/'.$filename;


        // create directory to move file into if it doesn't exist
        mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);

        // is the file moved to the proper folder successfully?
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$sf]['tmp_name'], $myTarget)) {
            // set a new placeholder with the new full path (if you need it in subsequent hooks)
            $modx->setPlaceholder('fi.'.$sf.'_new', $myTarget);
            // set the permissions on the file
            if (!chmod($myTarget, 0644)) { /*some debug function*/ }

        } else {
            // File not uploaded
            $errorMsg = 'There was a problem uploading the file.';
            $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
            $output = false; // generate submission error
        }

    } else {
        // File type not allowed
        $errorMsg = 'Type of file not allowed.';
        $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
        $output = false; // generate submission error
    }

// if no file, don't error, but return blank
} else {
    $hook->setValue($sf, '');
}

}

return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar coded for my website, this code is super old so don't judge or use it directly. Just an example.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
//Get the temp file path
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

//Make sure we have a filepath
if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
//Setup our new file path
$newFilePath = "../FOLDER NAME/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

//Upload the file into the temp dir
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
    copy($newFilePath, $newFilePath1);
    $filename = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
    // add $filename to list or database here
            $result = "The files were uploaded succesfully.";
}else{
            $result = "There was an error adding the files, please try again!";

}
}
}
```